# Globally Optimal String Substitutions

Tags: string, algorithm, encoding

I'm looking for some pointers for writing a function (let's call it `replaceGlobal`) that takes an input string and a mapping of substrings to replacement values, and applies these mappings such that as many characters as possible from the input string are replaced. For example:

```
replaceGlobal("abcde", {
    'a' -> 'w',
    'abc' -> 'x',
    'ab' -> 'y',
    'cde' -> 'z'
})
```

would return `"yz"` by applying `'ab' -> 'y'` and `'cde' -> 'z'`.

The function will only apply one round of substitutions, so it can't replace a value and then use part of the replacement value as part of another substitution.

A greedy approach produces non-optimal results (shown here in Javascript):

```
"abcde".replace(/(abc|cde|ab|a)/g, function(x) {
    return {
        'a': 'w',
        'abc': 'x',
        'ab': 'y',
        'cde': 'z'
    }[x];
});
```

returns `'xde'`

Any thoughts on a good starting point here?

I think the problem boils down to finding the lowest cost path in a weighted DAG constructed with the input string as a spine and other edges provided by the substitutions:

```
   /------x------------\
  /-----y------\        \
 /---w--\       \        \ /-------z------\
0 -----> a ----> b -----> c -----> d ----> e ----> $
```

where edges along the spine have a cost of 1 but the other edges have cost zero.

But that may be overcomplicating things.

Comment: Can you add a rule for `'abcde' -> 'yz'`, and so on?

Comment: @BrentWashburne If I understand you correctly, no. Generating all possible permutations of substitutions from the initial set is not reasonable. Please clarify if that is not what you are suggesting.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was suggesting.  How about putting `'cde' -> 'z'` first?

Comment: This problem has a pretty simple left-to-right scanning dynamic programming solution that takes O(N*M) time, where N is the length of your string and M is the length of the longest string you're searching for.  The finer points depend on the implementation language.  What language are you working in?  Also, do you want to do this in real production code?

Comment: Oh, and the solution looks a lot like the picture you drew.   Working from left to right, you only have to consider the edges that jump over the current position.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) is the way to go. This is due to the restriction:

> The function will only apply one round of substitutions, so it can't
>   replace a value and then use part of the replacement value as part of
>   another substitution.

Specifically, say you have some random string **abcdefg** as input. Now you apply some rule to substitute some middle part, say *de -> x*. Now you have **abc**x**fg**, where the only (smaller subproblems) strings you are now allowed to manipulate are **abc** and **fg**. And for repetitive substrings, you can then leverage [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Matt Timmermans comments and the original DAG idea, here's what I came up with in Javascript as a first attempt (I'm more interested in the algorithm itself than any specific language implementation):

```
const replaceGlobal = (str, dict) => {
    let open = []; // set of substitutions being actively explored
    let best = { value: [], weight: 0 }; // optimal path info

    // For each character in the input string, left to right
    for (let c of str) {
        // Add new nodes to `open` for all `substitutions` that
        // start with `c`
        for (let entry of dict)
            if (entry.match[0] === c)
                open.push({
                    value: best.value.concat(entry.sub),
                    rest: entry.match,
                    weight: best.weight
                });

        // Add current character onto best path
        best.value.push(c);
        ++best.weight;

        // For each `open` path, try to match against the current character
        let new_open = [];
        for (let o of open) {
            if (o.rest[0] === c) {
                if (o.rest.length > 1) { // still more to match
                    new_open.push({
                        rest: o.rest.slice(1),
                        value: o.value,
                        weight: o.weight
                    });
                } else { // full match found
                    if (o.weight < best.weight)
                        best = o;
                }
            }
        }
        open = new_open;
    }
    return best.value.join('');
};
```

Which would be used:

```
replaceGlobal('abcde', [
    { match: 'a', sub: 'w' },
    { match: 'abc', sub: 'x' },
    { match: 'ab', sub: 'y' },
    { match: 'cde', sub: 'z' }
])) === 'yz'
```

It passes some simple unit tests, but I may be overlooking something silly and it still seems more complicated than needed.

You could also make `dict` a trie of characters to make looking up the matches easier (and do the same with `open`). Even with the trie, I believe this approach would still be `O(str.length * dict.length)` though.